# Showing a column by clicking a button

Tags: angular, angular-material

I need to show a column when the user clicks on an `Edit` button. The column will show a delete symbol in the "Actions" column. I am not sure on how to do it. If I add "Actions" into `displayedColumn`, the edit button will not work and it prompted an error stated multiple bindings.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="button">
  <button mat-button (click)="toggleButton()"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
    Edit </button>
</div>

<div class="Edit" *ngIf="showDetails">     
             <div class="form-container">
                <div>Edit</div>
                <mat-form-field class="subjectCode">
                    <input matInput  placeholder="Subject Code">                  
                </mat-form-field>           
            </div>                  
</div>


<div class="table-container">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="subjectData">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Subject Number">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>#</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let i = index">{{ i + 1 }}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Subject_Code">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Subject
        Code</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.Subject_Code 
              }}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Subject Name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Subject
        Name</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.Subject_Name 
              }}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="showDetails" matColumnDef="Actions">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Action</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <button mat-button><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
  </table>
</div>
```

**TS:**

```
export class SubjectListComponent implements OnInit {

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['Number', 'Subject_Code',
    'Subject_Name', 'Actions'
  ];

  showDetails: boolean;

  constructor() {
    this.showDetails = false;
  }

  toggleButton() {
    this.showDetails = !this.showDetails;
  }
}
```

Comment: you can get entire row

Comment: i want the column "Actions" only appear when user click on the "Edit" Button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just show/hide the column by adding/removing the name of the column to the `displayedColumns` array.

> Check out
>   [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-e4wznm?file=app/app.component.ts)
>   stackblitz.

The main change would be in the `toggleButton` function (and remove the `showDetails` property all together):

```
toggleButton() {
  let index = this.displayedColumns.indexOf('Actions');
  if (index > -1) {
    this.displayedColumns.splice(index, 1);
  } else {
    this.displayedColumns.push('Actions');
  }
}
```

Comment: What is not working? Any error messages? As you can see in the stackblitz it works fine, there must still be some issue in your code. Can you show the updated code?

Comment: i need  the showDetails because I need the Edit section to appear

Comment: No you don't. As you can see in the stackblitz, Angular Material handles that for you. It shows exactly the columns you pass to the table in `displayedColumns`. By modifying this array of column names, you can easily show and hide columns.

Comment: but i don't have `symbol` in const ELEMENT_DATA. I did not use any Element_Data The table is getting its data from the database.

Comment: That doesn't matter. I just used an Angular Material example to showcase how it works. For you, you need to add/remove `'Actions'` to `displayedColumns`. Where the data comes from doesn't matter as we are just modifying the table structure. Edit: I updated the function in the answer so it will work for you.

Comment: do I still remain *ngIf="showDetails " <ng-container *ngIf="showDetails" matColumnDef="Actions"> in my code?

Comment: No, remove the ngIf

Comment: Thank you so much. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

check out

[javascript-grid-selection](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-selection/)

You can either get the focused cell by using

```
var focusedCell = gridOptions.api.getFocusedCell();
```

or use the onCellFocused event.

Both give you the following properties:

```
rowIndex: number
column: Column
```

Use the row-index to retrieve the row-node:

```
var row = gridOptions.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(rowIndex);
```

After that you can use those properties to retrieve the raw value of the cell:

```
var cellValue = gridOptions.api.getValue(colKey, row.node)
```

Comment: wait i will check

Comment: you want to add to .ts file

Answer (score 0):

You can either get the focused cell by using

```
var focusedCell = gridOptions.api.getFocusedCell();
```

or use the onCellFocused event.

Both give you the following properties:

```
rowIndex: number
column: Column
```

Use the row-index to retrieve the row-node:

```
var row = gridOptions.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(rowIndex);
```

After that you can use those properties to retrieve the raw value of the cell:

```
var cellValue = gridOptions.api.getValue(colKey, row.node)
```